# Preventing URI Navigation in vaadin

Tags: java, spring-security, uri, vaadin

I am using the java framework Vaadin to create a web application. There different user levels for this application, and when the user logs in I change the menu depending on their permission level. The problem I am having is preventing a user from visiting a page they are not suppose to by typing in the URI. For example if a user logs in to the application and only has permission to view page one he can still access page two by typing the URI to page two in the browsers search bar.

I was looking into preventing URI navigation, but was unsuccessful in finding out how this is done in Vaadin. So my question is how to prevent URI navigation in Vaadin? If you have a different method of preventing users from accessing pages they are not suppose to please feel free to post that as well.

So far i've come up short and the one post that i've seen about this on stack overflow does not explain it particularly well.

So far this is what my NavigatorUI class looks like:

```
@SpringUI
public class NavigatorUI extends UI {

    public Navigator navigator;
    public static final String LOGIN = "";
    public static final String MAINPAGE = "main";
    public static final String EMPLOYEEPAGE = "employeepage";
    public static final String REGISTERPAGE = "registerpage";
    public static final String ADDEMPLOYEEPAGE = "addemployeepage";
    public static final String ADDEMPLOYERPAGE = "addemployerpage";

    private MainSystem main = new MainSystem();

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);
        setContent(layout);
        Navigator.ComponentContainerViewDisplay viewDisplay = new Navigator.ComponentContainerViewDisplay(layout);
        navigator = new Navigator(UI.getCurrent(), viewDisplay);
        navigator.addView(LOGIN, new LoginView());
        navigator.addView(MAINPAGE, new MainView());
        navigator.addView(EMPLOYEEPAGE, new EmployeeView());
        navigator.addView(REGISTERPAGE, new RegisterView());
        navigator.addView(ADDEMPLOYEEPAGE, new AddEmployeeView());
        navigator.addView(ADDEMPLOYERPAGE, new AddEmployerView());
        navigator.addViewChangeListener(new ViewChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean beforeViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
          View newView = event.getNewView();
            String newViewString= newView.toString();
            newViewString = newViewString.substring(0,newViewString.length()-9);
            View loginView = new LoginView();
            String loginViewString = loginView.toString();
                    loginViewString = loginViewString.substring(0,loginViewString.length()-9);
            boolean result = true;
            if (newViewString.equals(loginViewString)){
                return result;
            }
            else if (VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("role").toString().equals("Admin")||VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute("role").toString().equals("Employee")){
                return result;
            }
            else {
            result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }

     @Override
     public void afterViewChange(ViewChangeEvent event) {
     //NO-OP
     }
      });
    }
    }
```

Comment: You have to prevent the URL to work in two places: In the UI and server side in the controller handling the UI. So if the user is not allowed to view the URL, the page instead renders an error message.

Comment: You are using `Navigator`?

Comment: yes, post updated with navigator code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a `ViewchangeListener` to your `Navigator` instance, that can prevent navigation in the [`beforeViewChange`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.1.7/com/vaadin/navigator/ViewChangeListener.html#beforeViewChange-com.vaadin.navigator.ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent-).

> If any listener returns false, the view change is not allowed and afterViewChange() methods are not called.

So you implement that Interface with a check of the current users authorizations against the `newView` of the event.  And in case you want to block that, you return `false` there.

Comment: Yup i've got it and added the code as below but how would i implement a check to see if that user is allowed to see the view.....i'd like anyone to see the login view but not the main page view.....i've updated the code with the view change listener.

Comment: Well you ahve to implement that.  You mentioned, you already did it for the menu.  So it's the same here.

Comment: Ok so i've got that for the menu but that when a user is already entered into the VaadinSession attribute of "role"....at this point we don't know the users role as they haven't logged in yet so they are Anon... the key point being that the beforecall listener is stopping me seeing the Login page altogether so ideally i'd like anyone to see the Login page but only people who are logged in to see the other pages...I'm using VaadinSession as a holder of the role for that session? Sorry if these seem like bone questions...every day is a school day! updated code...

Comment: You allow every user to visit the login page there.  Put a check first like: `if (newView is Login) return true`.  Same with maybe other public views (e.g. put them in a white list, annotate them, ...)

Comment: You were the only one to answer and gave me a good line to take! i've added the complete code to help others with their struggles. 

The issue i found was comparing Vaadin Views with the only way of comparing them being breaking them down into their string values and comparing like that.

anyway many thanks for the help dude!